# Store records in a new table created by a query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables ,location and locationdata. I want to query data from both the tables using join and to store the result in a new table(locationCreatedNew) which is not already present in the MySQL.Can I do this in MySQL?

> SELECT location.id,locationdata.name INTO locationCreatedNew FROM
>   location RIGHT JOIN locationdata ON
>   location.id=locationdata.location_location_id;

Comment: Do you mean `locationCreatedNew` table is not created yet and you want to create it when running this SQL ?

Comment: yes. I want to create locationCreatedNew  table through the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample code in OP is syntax in SQL Server, the counter part of that in MySQL is something like:

```
 CREATE TABLE locationCreatedNew 
 SELECT * FROM location RIGHT JOIN locationdata 
 ON location.id=locationdata.location_location_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Query like below.

```
create table new_tbl as
select col1, col2, col3 from old_tbl t1, old_tbl t2
where condition;
```

Comment: I need to perform join over the tables so this wouldn't be helpful in that case

Comment: I have tried below query and it worked fine.
    create table temp as 
    SELECT user_role_id, role, user_roles.username
     FROM user_roles , users
      where users.username = user_roles.username;

Answer (score 0):

Referance: [CREATE TABLE ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-select.html)

For *CREATE TABLE ... SELECT*, the destination table does not preserve information about whether columns in the selected-from table are generated columns. The SELECT part of the statement cannot assign values to generated columns in the destination table.

Some conversion of data types might occur. For example, the *AUTO_INCREMENT* attribute is not preserved, and *VARCHAR* columns can become *CHAR* columns. Retrained attributes are *NULL* (or *NOT NULL*) and, for those columns that have them, *CHARACTER SET*, *COLLATION*, *COMMENT*, and the *DEFAULT* clause.

When creating a table with *CREATE TABLE ... SELECT*, make sure to alias any function calls or expressions in the query. If you do not, the *CREATE* statement might fail or result in undesirable column names.

```
CREATE TABLE newTbl
SELECT tbl1.clm, COUNT(tbl2.tbl1_id) AS number_of_recs_tbl2
FROM tbl1 LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.id = tbl2.tbl1_id
GROUP BY tbl1.id;
```

**NOTE**: `newTbl` is the name of the new table you want to create. You can use `SELECT * FROM othertable` which is the query that returns the data the table should be created from.

You can also explicitly specify the data type for a column in the created table:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (a TINYINT NOT NULL) SELECT b+1 AS a FROM bar;
```

For *CREATE TABLE ... SELECT*, if *IF NOT EXISTS* is given and the target table exists, nothing is inserted into the destination table, and the statement is not logged.

To ensure that the binary log can be used to re-create the original tables, *MySQL* does not permit concurrent inserts during *CREATE TABLE ... SELECT*.

You cannot use *FOR UPDATE* as part of the *SELECT* in a statement such as `CREATE TABLE new_table SELECT ... FROM old_table` .... If you attempt to do so, the statement fails.

Please check it for more. Hope this help you.